# how to use asyncio to split streaming data and its working

Tags: python

have the following code to stream data and execute certain calculations
the codes are made async for the functions to run one after the another after certain breaks.

async def on_ticks gives the streaming data.
async def on_connect connects to the web socket.
async def works does the calculation of the streamed data.

although the code seems correct i get warning

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'on_connect' was never awaited
  self.on_connect(self, response

RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

where am i wrong.

'''

df=pd.DataFrame(data=None)

```
  async def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
   global df
   for sc in ticks:
       token=sc['instrument_token']
       name=trd_portfolio[token]['name']
       ltp=sc['last_price']
       df1=pd.DataFrame([name,ltp]).T
       df1.columns=['name','ltp']
       df=df.append(df1,ignore_index=True)

       await asyncio.sleep(5)

  async def work():
      global df
   df['change']=df.groupby('name')['ltp'].pct_change()
   g = df.groupby('name')['change']
   g = g.agg(
    pos_count=lambda s: s.gt(0).sum(),
    neg_count=lambda s: s.lt(0).sum(),
    net_count=lambda s: s.gt(0).sum()- s.lt(0).sum()).astype(int)
   g=g.sort_values(by=['net_count'])
   print(g)

   await asyncio.sleep(1)    


  async def on_connect(ws, response):

      ws.subscribe(inst_token)
      ws.set_mode(ws.MODE_LTP,inst_token)

   await asyncio.sleep(1)

  kws.on_ticks = on_ticks
  kws.on_connect = on_connect
  kws.connect()

     async def main():
         await asyncio.gather(
             on_connect(),
             on_ticks(),
             work()
             )

     asyncio.run(main())
```

'''